# Nested divs producing a scrollbar. Why?

Tags: html, css, border-box

I have 3 nested divs:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><div class="item"></div></div>
</div>
```

The .inner div is position absolute and they each have 1px border:

```
.outer{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.inner{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item{
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This arrangement results in a scrollbar on the .outer div.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojWVVN)

Why is this and what do I need to change to stop it happening?

If the width of the border of the .inner div is increased to 3px then the scrollbar goes away. Again, why is this happening?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvbNXp i will post answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your `.item` element is set to display as an `inline-block`. This means it's affected by things like `line-height` and `vertical-align`.

The default vertical alignment on `inline-block` elements is baseline. This means they're set to appear at the base line of any text that may be entered alongside it. I'm not 100% sure but I think there may be an issue here where `box-sizing` is ignored when making this calculation, and the base line ends up being 2 pixels below where it should be (due to the cumulative 2 pixels of border applied to the top and bottom of the element).

If you want that element to remain being displayed this way, a quick fix is to set its `vertical-align` to `top`:

```css
.item {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvbNmK).

Comment: @WillJenkins I'm not sure what you mean. If you want the `.item` element to appear centred, you can give your `.inner` element a `width` of `100%` and a `text-align` set to `center`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmRQpL

Comment: Removing `display: inline-block`, setting either `vertical-align: top/middle/bottom` or `position: absolute` on item all work, but why does the inline-block child of an absolutely positioned element take up space in the parent anyway??

Comment: @Tyblitz I've updated my answer with a theory as to why I think this happens.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I mean vertically centered. Now, by doing this the scroll bar goes away: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MamRpL

Comment: @WillJenkins the `middle` vertical-alignment here will only work if it has something to align itself against. If we remove `.item1` from that the vertical alignment stops working. You could however apply a `line-height` of `98px` on your `.inner` element to achieve this.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That sounds logical to me, and I've also encountered this 2px-ish change before.. +1

Comment: Hah, ok @JamesDonnelly - new challenge is to add the line-height and then make a vertically-aligned single item fit without a gap at the top or a scroll bar http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPmgOE

Comment: maybe I should write a new question... ?

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996119/css-vertical-alignment-with-nested-divs

Answer (score 2):

The weirdest thing is that if you remove `overflow-x:hidden;` the scrollbar goes away. The reason is that the default behavior of `overflow` is `visible` thus if you don't mess with it, the results will be no scrollbars, **but** setting `overflow-x` to some value, sets `overflow-y` to `auto` instead of the default value which is `visible` and as a result, the scrollbar appears.

If you set `overflow` to `auto` the scrollbar will also appear.

On the other hand, `.item` is set to `inline-block` so it has `line-height` which produces the space on the bottom. Setting `.inner` to `line-height:0` will make the space disappear, and if you increase it it will increase as well.

On the other ( third hand ) you can just constrict the space that the elements inside `.inner` take by setting `.inner` to `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Yeah I knew this but overflow-x:hidden is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `inline-block` in the inner item? If you change to block your scroll disappears:

```
.item{
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  display: block;
  border:1px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because your height is 100% then you're adding 1px of border on each div. Working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvbNXp

So your .inner and .item classes need the height changed to:

```
height:calc(100% - 1px);
```

Comment: Nope, box-sizing:border-box takes the border width in to account.

Comment: I believe the box-sizing only takes into account the padding and margin, right?  Because this solution takes away the scrollbar

Comment: Nope. It's padding and border but not margin. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Okay.  I think it's the whitespace on your inline-block element.  https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/  Remove that and you're good.  And vote my answer back up while you're at it ;)

Comment: Oh. sorry.  But if you do remove inline-block from the .item class it's fixed, or if you add margin: -1px.  Plus there are issues of whitespace with inline-block elements, as noted in that article