# Css vertical alignment with nested divs

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, border-box

This question resulted from a fix suggested to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995076/nested-divs-producing-a-scrollbar-why)

I have 3 nested divs: outer, inner and item.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"><div class="item"></div></div>
</div>
```

Given the following basic CSS:

```
.outer{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.inner{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:98px;
}
.item{
  width:100px;
  height:94px;
  background-color:yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The challenge is to center the 'item' div vertically with equal (or no) gaps above/below, and no vertical scrollbars appearing.

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPmgBR)

Update:

As pointed out below, I should add that multiple items of different heights must be centered. The best answer so far is to add a negative margin to each item, resulting in the following: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYWEYZ

However, this smells bad (to me) as it requires an offset that depends on 3 other properties.

Comment: there is so much hacky stuff here, why not just add another:  margin-top: -5px; to the .item class centers it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPmgBR

Comment: seems like it, with the 98px line-height, have to have overflow-x: hidden, have to have inline-block on the .item class.  Either way, the margin-top: -5px fixes it because it adjusts to the 1px border for outer and inner (4px total) and line-height difference.  If you make the borders 2px on outer and inner (8px total) then then margin top becomes -9px and it is fine.  It's all about the borders, with the line-height thrown in

Comment: None of those things are hacky, they're required by the design. It's for an image carousel, the images are different heights and need to be stacked up together (needing inline-block), the overflow hidden is to only show some of the images at a time, yada yada. It's all required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbmRjo

to add this to your .item class:

```
margin-top: -5px;
```

It's because of the borders on your outer and inner classes, as well as the line-height of the inner class.  If you make the borders 2px instead of 1px, then the margin top becomes -9px.  If you leave borders at 1px and make the line-height 96px the margin top becomes -3px.

So why can't you use a negative margin top?

Comment: This does work (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYWEYZ) but it smells bad. The fact that we have to allow for 3 other dimensions outside the item is not great but if no-one else has a better solution I'll accept this answer...

Comment: I agree that it stinks a bit.  It's definitely an interesting scenario though - is this something you're working on, or just curious about?

Answer (score 0):

If you use flexbox, this is easily achieved:

```
.inner{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:98px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: I've found inconsistent behaviour on mobiles with flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell;` to get the vertical centering you want:

```
.outer{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.inner{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:98px;
  display: table; //must change this as well
}
.item{
  width:100px;
  height:94px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border:1px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell; //update display type
}
```

Comment: but if I have elements that are different heights and I actually want them centered this doesn't work

Comment: This assumes that the middle<div> is always going to be 100% of the outer div. The outer and item divs can be flexible in height. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Here's a codepen with two items of different heights: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avWrzB

Comment: ah, gotcha. Wasn't expecting multiple inner divs - oops :)

Comment: maybe add that constraint to your question and example: i won't be the only person not to extend this properly!